# My R functions intended to randomly assign participants to groups and simulate differences in means is not running through a pipe

Tags: r, function, simulation

I've created a random dataset using set.seed(1101) - r(studio) version 4.0

```
set.seed(1101)
library(tidyverse)
dat <- readr::read_csv("..data/datafile.csv")
```

My intention was to simulate randomly assigning participants to two groups of equal size and calculate the differences between their group mean scores, then create a distribution of these scores.

I have created functions to do these operations.

Group assignment function (A or B) labelled Permute ('group' is the name of the variable in the dataset)

```
permute <- function(x) {
  x %>% 
    mutate(group = sample(group, replace = TRUE))
  }
```

Calculating differences in mean scores between two groups from a tibble and inputting it into a function called calc_diff:

```
calc_diff <- function(x) { 
  x %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    summarise(m = mean(Y)) %>% 
    spread(group, m) %>% 
    mutate(diff = A - B) %>% 
    pull(diff) 
  }
```

When I run these functions individually in the console, they simulate differences just fine for the data object.

```
Permute(x = dat) ## original data tibble
Calc_diffs(x = dat)
```

So I created a pipe to join these functions and store the output in a variable called dat_sim:

```
dat_sim <- dat %>% 
  permute() %>% # group assignment
  calc_diff() # mean differences calc
```

Problem is that when I try to replicate that 1000 times through a pipe I get all instances of the same score, not randomly varied outputs. The code I have used is below.

```
dat_sim1000 <- rep(dat2 %>% 
                     permute() %>%
                     calc_diff(), 1000) # put replications at the end as for some reason it just replicated the number 1000 when I put it at the start
```

Thus for some reason the replicate function is not re-running the function 1000 times for different results but running both once and storing the output a 1000 times. What do I need to do to re-run the functions a 1000 times and store the output?

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is not your functions but the way you are trying to repeat the process.
`rep` does just take its first argument an repeats it.

Try the following:

```r
dat_sim1000 <- map(1:1000,
                   ~dat2 %>% 
                     permute() %>%
                     calc_diff())
```

You could also use `lapply` or a loop instead of `map`. It just repeats the term given after the `~` as many times as there are values in the vector `1:1000`

---

#### EDIT

An example that should work:

```r
set.seed(1101)
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tibble(group = sample(LETTERS[1:2],50,T),
              Y = rnorm(50))

permute <- function(x) {
  x %>% 
    mutate(group = sample(group, replace = TRUE))
}


calc_diff <- function(x) { 
  x %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    summarise(m = mean(Y)) %>% 
    spread(group, m) %>% 
    mutate(diff = A - B) %>% 
    pull(diff) 
}

dat_sim1000 <- map(1:1000,
                   ~dat %>% 
                     permute() %>%
                     calc_diff())
summary(unlist(dat_sim1000))
#>      Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
#> -0.740541 -0.188444 -0.004183 -0.003256  0.183467  0.821315
```

Comment: Unfortunately tried both of those suggestions but no luck. Still returning the same number over and over again. So it applies the arguments once, not 1000 times to create different results which is what I'm looking for. Also no luck using lapply, as it could not find the function. Albeit never used the latter before so my syntax may be wrong.

Comment: That is strange. Is there maybe an issue with your `dat2`?
I'll edit my answer with the example that worked for me. Does it work for you too?

Comment: seems like I just used the wrong function to begin with, but thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You may be confusing `rep` and `replicate`: `rep` just repeats its first argument. `replicate`, by contrast, repeatedly evaluates a given expression.

Note that the order of arguments is inverted (because who needs consistent APIs?):

```
dat_sim1000 = replicate(
    1000L,
    dat2 %>% permute() %>% calc_diff()
)
```